# What is difference between grid layer and feature Layer in mapbox map?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have created polygon using two way but i have not understand difference between them.

1. using grid layer

   http://bl.ocks.org/rclark/7043524
2. using feature layer......

   ```
   L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZ2F1cmF2Y2F0c3RlY2giLCJhIjoiY2l1cGo0MTl4MDAxajJ1bng5a2xieTY0diJ9.0fDXNulI91U85ngSc4jGCg';

   var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
   .setView([38.89399, -77.03659], 17);

   L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/gauravcatstech/civ82vos7008f2is5x92cpvye').addTo(map);

   var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
   var circle_options = {
       color: '#fff',      // Stroke color
       opacity: 1,         // Stroke opacity
       weight: 10,         // Stroke weight
       fillColor: '#000',  // Fill color
       fillOpacity: 0.6    // Fill opacity
   };

   var line_points = [
       [38.893596444352134, -77.0381498336792],
       [38.89337933372204, -77.03792452812195],
       [38.89316222242831, -77.03761339187622],
       [38.893028615148424, -77.03731298446655],
       [38.892920059048464, -77.03691601753235],
       [38.892903358095296, -77.03637957572937],
       [38.89301191422077, -77.03592896461487],
       [38.89316222242831, -77.03549981117249],
       [38.89340438498248, -77.03514575958252],
       [38.893596444352134, -77.0349633693695]
   ];

   var polyline_options = {
       color: '#000'
   };

   var polyline = L.polygon(line_points, polyline_options).addTo(featureGroup);

   var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
       edit: {
           featureGroup: featureGroup
       }
   }).addTo(map);

   map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
       featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
   });
   ```

Comment: if i do like this..   var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'rclark.h2jc29lj', {
                gridControl: false,
            }).setView([36.18111, -110.44555], 9);
            myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
            var states=data_1; 
       
            myLayer.setGeoJSON(states);

Comment: it shows the polygon .....then why we are using gridlayer in first example

Answer (score 2):

In the first case the polygon data is in GeoJSON tiles, and in the second case the data is defined inline in the JS code.